# Форма загрузки файлов

Tags: html, php

Вот пример кода:

```
<form action="handler.php">
    <p><strong>Укажите картинку</strong></p>
    <p><input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Мне здесь не понятно, что должно быть в handler.php, чтобы загрузка файлов производилась в `/file/image/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых,

```
<form action="handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Во-вторых, handler.php

```
<?
if (empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) die('Файл не принят сервером');
$tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$fname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'file/image/'.$fname)) die('Не удалось переместить файл из временной папки');
echo '<img src="/file/image/'.$fname.'" />'; // картинка загружена
?>
```